# saving model with deep association belonging to both higher models

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.7

I have three tables, `Articles`, `Comments`, and `Tags`.

`Tags` belong to both `Articles` and `Comments`.

```
$this->Articles->patchEntity($entity, $this->request->getData(), [
    'associated' => ['Comments.Tags']
]);
```

with the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'article_id' doesn't have a default value 

Please try correcting the issue for the following table aliases:

    CommentsArticles
```

but if I save with only `'associated' => ['Comments']` it works saving the `Article` and `Comments` with join table associations, just doesn't save any `Tags`.

`Articles` table has these associations:

```
$this->hasMany('Tags', [
  'foreignKey' => 'article_id'
]);
$this->belongsToMany('Comments', [
  'foreignKey' => 'article_id',
  'targetForeignKey' => 'comment_id',
  'joinTable' => 'comments_articles'
]);
```

`Comments` table has these associations:

```
$this->hasMany('Tags', [
  'foreignKey' => 'comment_id'
]);
$this->belongsToMany('Articles', [
  'foreignKey' => 'comment_id',
  'targetForeignKey' => 'article_id',
  'joinTable' => 'comments_articles'
]);
```

and `Tags` table has these associations:

```
$this->belongsTo('Comments', [
  'foreignKey' => 'comment_id',
  'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
$this->belongsTo('Articles', [
  'foreignKey' => 'article_id',
  'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

This is the entity after patching looks like this.

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Article) {

    'title' => 'example article name',
    'users' => [
        '_ids' => []
    ],
    'comments' => [
        (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Comment) {
            'id' => (int) 1,
            'content' => 'this is a comment',
            'tags' => [
                (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Tag) {

                    'name' => 'example tag name',
                    '[new]' => true,
                    '[accessible]' => [
                        'comment_id' => true,
                        'article_id' => true,
                        'comment' => true,
                        'article' => true
                    ],
                    '[dirty]' => [
                        'name' => true
                    ],
                    '[original]' => [],
                    '[virtual]' => [],
                    '[hasErrors]' => false,
                    '[errors]' => [],
                    '[invalid]' => [],
                    '[repository]' => 'Tags'

                }
            ],
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                'content' => true,
                'tags' => true,
                'articles' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [
                'tags' => true
            ],
            '[original]' => [
                'tags' => [
                    (int) 0 => [
                        'name' => '0'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[hasErrors]' => false,
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Comments'

        }
    ],
    '[new]' => true,
    '[accessible]' => [
        'title' => true,
        'tags' => true,
        'comments' => true,
        'users' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [
        'title' => true,
        'users' => true,
        'comments' => true
    ],
    '[original]' => [
        'users' => []
    ],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[hasErrors]' => false,
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Articles'

}
```

Comment: Try ```'associated' => ['Comments', 'Comments.Tags']```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CaekPHP doesn't support that, it can only populate foreign keys of direct associations / in one direction. You could for example:

- prepopulate the foreign key fields (which will of course only work when the article and/or comment already exists)
- manually save the tags separately using the primary keys of the article and comment records
- create association classes that pass the article primary key into the options when saving the article, and uses that to populate the `article_id` field when saving the tag
- hook into the saving process on table level to pass on the article primary key and populate the tags with it

Here's a quick and dirty example for the latter solution, which should also give you an idea on how it could work on association level:

In `ArticlesTable`:

```
public function beforeSave(
    \Cake\Event\Event $event,
    \Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity,
    \ArrayObject $options
) {
    if (isset($options['Articles.id'])) {
        unset($options['Articles.id']);
    }
}

protected function _onSaveSuccess($entity, $options)
{
    if ($options['_primary']) {
        $options['Articles.id'] = $entity->get('id');
    }

    return parent::_onSaveSuccess($entity, $options);
}
```

In `TagsTable`:

```
public function beforeSave(
    \Cake\Event\Event $event,
    \Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity,
    \ArrayObject $options
) {
    if (!$options['_primary'] &&
        isset($options['Articles.id'])
    ) {
        $entity->set('article_id', $options['Articles.id']);
    }
}
```